# How to know if a page has been modified between 2 visits - cache system - PHP

Tags: php, caching, curl

I'm using cURL php to display content, I know cURL can be resourceful and obviously increase loading time so I'm trying to implement a cache logic system to read HTML content from a file and not using cURL.
Now my question is how to determine if a page has been updated compared to cache version between 2 visits without doing a cURL request?

My cURL function at the moment is as follow:

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
    {
           $ch = curl_init($url);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
           return @curl_exec($ch);
    }
```

Your ideas and suggestions are more than welcome! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @RyanVincent I understand your point on a lifetime perspective but what about on an update perspective? Update cache if page is updated. Somehow check if content is different without getting the whole content or without doing a cURL request. Maybe informations from headers? filesize? I don't know...

Comment: @RyanVincent Yes it's my own website. Do you think I shouldn't be using cURL to get HTML content of a compiled page? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Because it's a Wordpress thing...Wanna make easy and not have to deal with all widgets, pages, posts, sidebars,...

Comment: So I'm doing cURL request to get the final output of a page and modify it according what I wanna do.